# Display number of questions randomly

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to display randomly just 2 of the 3 questions (example as follows).

I know it is with Math.log() but I can't figure it out.

*EDIT: I mean Math.random()*

My idea is to have aprox. 100 questions and every time the quiz is attempted, just display 5. In this way, every time the quiz is different.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
(function() {
function buildQuiz() {
  const output = [];

  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    const answers = [];

    for (var letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
      answers.push(
        `<label>
        <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
        ${letter} :
        ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
      </label>`
      );
    }

    output.push(
      `<div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>`
    );
  });

  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
}
const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the best site ever created?",
    answers: {
      a: "SitePoint",
      b: "Simple Steps Code",
      c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Where is Waldo really?",
    answers: {
      a: "Antarctica",
      b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
      c: "Sitting in a tree",
      d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  },

];
```

Comment: What does the natural logarithm have to do with it? O.o

Comment: Well, I thought I need this Math.log() for displaying the questions randomly, but I guess I am wrong?

Comment: `Math.random()` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I add it? (I will edit the question)

Comment: Does the duplicate solve your problem? If not what's the remaining problem?

Comment: No, it does not. The remaining problem is the the same as the question above :s

Comment: More clarification needed. Now you know how to pick 2 random ones, [edit] the question for necessary information.

Comment: I just don't know where to add Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuestions.length)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `myQuestions` array of size 3 and you want to randomly pick 2 questions from it. You can use `Math.random()` to select random indices from your array. For an array of size 3, you can do this as follows:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuestions.length)
```

You can call it twice to get two random indices and you can ask the questions corresponding to those indices. For a larger question set, you can do this random selection in a loop.

Comment: I am pretty new with JavaScript. Where should I introduce this line of code? Thanks for your help.